# Trying to run as function to recognize certain strings in a list and reiterate them

Tags: python

```
iput = []

final = []

while True:
    iput += [input('Enter words here: ')]
    if not iput[-1]:
        break

z = 1
while i < len(iput) - 1:
    print(i)
while iput[i][0] != iput[i][z]:
    if z == len(iput[i]):
        break
        z += 1
        i += 1

print(final)
```

Comment: What means the `final` variable ? Identation is OK? If there is loop in loop... so it's bad, or no?

Comment: so im trying to get the final to be the returned list of specified words but not quite sure how to get it in there

Comment: Your question and problem are unclear. Please provide them clearly, including your input and expected output. Also, the `final` variable in your code is useless.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand what you want to do. The `final` variable was not used anywhere - it is declared as a blank `<list>` at the start of the code, and then at the end there is only a `print()` statement from that variable. What do you need to get the output data out of `final`? Boolean type? Dictionary? A list with what items? Or with one item (which item please)? Or what exactly? It would be best if you give an example of data (especially the output ones). Also, I can't see in the code which string you're looking for in the `iput` list.